# MongoDB Error when using UnionWith and NewRoot

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zS6XXCKnSkV)

I have 2 collections:

```
Asset {Name, Price}

Client {Name, Email, Assets: {Name, Price}}
```

Collection Asset and the prop Client.Asset have the same structure.

When a client does not have the prop asset populated, that means that I need to get the default ones from Asset collection.

I am using .Net core and I dont whant to do 2 queries (one to find if client has the Assets, and if not, another one to get the assets).

So I was trying to use UnionWith, bringing de default Assets marked with xxx:0 and if the Client has Assets, bringing them marked with xxx:1, and then in the .Net I would do the magic...

But when I add the ReplaceRoot, it shows me an error message saying:  "Query failed with error code 40228 and error message ''newRoot' expression must evaluate to an object, but resulting value was: [{_id:...."

Why this error? coll.Client.Asset are an array of objects like coll.Asset...

Solving this problem, is there a more elegant way to do just one query? like if this works, in the case the client has assets, It will return Default ones + Client ones... this is not good.. would be good If I could do an IF on Mongo like - If Client Has, send Client Assets, if doesn´t, send default one...

Here there is [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zS6XXCKnSkV) without ReplaceRoot (so it´s returning the second part wrong)

thanks!

Query:

```
db.getCollection("Asset").aggregate(
    [
        {  "$match" : {  }
        }, 
        {  "$addFields" : {  "xxx" : "0" }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unionWith" : { 
                "coll" : "Client", 
                "pipeline" : [
                    {  "$match" : {  "_id" : ObjectId("5ca7d1310d8abc00026565ab") }
                    }, 
                    {  "$addFields" : { "Asset.xxx" : "1" }
                    }, 
                    {  "$project" : {  "Asset" : 1.0 }
                    }, 
                    {  "$replaceRoot" : { "newRoot" : "$Asset" }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

Comment: post some example document and expected result.

Comment: @turivishal just added and example at https://mongoplayground.net/p/zS6XXCKnSkV

Comment: Asset is an array so you have to unwind it before replaceRoot, so add `{ $unwind: "$Asset" }` before replaceRoot

Comment: Good point, forget about this... how about to add an IF on this, like, IF Client has assets, send Client.Asset, ELSE send Asset? I added xx= 0 or 1 to d o this on .net, but I think can be done on mongo....

Comment: i am not getting your point, can you explain more with example.

Comment: Running this aggregation with Unwind will return [{name: 1, price: 1, xx:0}, {name:1, price: 2, xx:1}]. I would like to add an extra stage to the aggregation saying: IF there is xx:1, remove where xx:0 nd return only ones with xx:1.

Comment: add match stage at last `{ $match: { xx: 1 } }`

Comment: This wont work for what I need, some times client does not have assets, in this case I need the x:0, and when they have, I need the x:1.. thats why I added xx so I could see if they are the default one (from col. Assets) or if they are from Client (coll.Client.Asset). Thanks.

Comment: oh i got it, its hard to do, i will try if possible.

Comment: i would suggest if you do 2 queries something like, first query get client.asset, `if` it has then return result `else` do second query to get default asset. i think this is the best solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231523/discussion-between-2fast4youbr-and-turivishal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But when I add the ReplaceRoot, it shows me an error message saying: "Query failed with error code 40228 and error message ''newRoot' expression must evaluate to an object, but resulting value was: [{_id:...."*
>
> *Why this error? coll.Client.Asset are an array of objects like coll.Asset...*

The $replaceRoot stage can replace array field to root, and Asset is an array, you have deconstruct it before replace to root,

```
{ $unwind: "$Asset" }
```

> *Solving this problem, is there a more elegant way to do just one query? like if this works, in the case the client has assets, It will return Default ones + Client ones... this is not good.. would be good If I could do an IF on Mongo like - If Client Has, send Client Assets, if doesn´t, send default one...*

> Comment: *some times client does not have assets, in this case I need the x:0, and when they have, I need the x:1.. thats why I added xx so I could see if they are the default one (from col. Assets) or if they are from Client (coll.Client.Asset).*

I would suggest if you do 2 separate queries something like, first query to get client.asset, if it has then return result else do second query to get default asset. i think this is the best solution,

- Find Client Assets:

```
var ClientAssets = await db.getCollection("Client").find({ "_id" : ObjectId("5ca7d1310d8abc00026565ab") });
```

- Check condition if Client Asset is empty:

```
if (!ClientAsset || !ClientAsset.Asset || !ClientAsset.Asset.length) {
   ClientAssets = await db.getCollection("Asset").find();
}

// RETURN RESULT
return ClientAssets;
```